# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a small application to view and edit mySQL tables.

I want to put ComboBox input inside the DataGridView, to choose data from foreign key in other table.

Is the any method to do so?

So far I have only found this code:

```
        Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data"
        cmb.Name = "cmb"
        cmb.DataSource = Form1.table
        cmb.DisplayMember = "adrese_id"
        cmb.ValueMember = "adrese_id"
        cmb.DataPropertyName = "adrese_id"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)

        Form1.adapter.Update(Form1.table)
```

This is my tables:

**abonenti**

abonents_id *PK*
vards
uzvards
tel_num
adrese_id *FK*

**adreses**

adrese_id *PK*
dziv_num
iela

When I select something from the comboBox it will just return to the value that is in the table. So I can't change it to any other.

Does somebody knows how to fix that, or how to make a comboBox working with foreign key inside the data grid view?

P.S. Also is there a way to place that select column instead the original?

Thanks.

Comment: My part of code started working after I added `Form1.table = New DataTable MainForm.adapter.Fill(Form1.table) DataGridView1.DataSource = Form1.table` after it. Mb that the reason WozzeC code is not working?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with when I did something similar.

After inserting data into the datagridview you convert the cell to a combobox. 
So basically you loop through the DGV like the code below and change the cell type. 
You set the dgvDropDown items to be the items from the database (as strings of course).
Just remember that if the value of the item isn't found in the drop down then an error will occur.

```
int column = 0     
For row As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dgvDropDown As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
        dgvDropDown.Items.Add("dbItem1")
        dgvDropDown.Items.Add("dbItem2")
        DataGridView1.Item(column, row) = dgvDropDown
Next
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you reply. I used your code, but I still can't get it to work. It shows possible selects, but when I select one of them it just ignores it and set back to what was in cell before.
Also, how to save changes from that ComboBoxCell to DataBase?
Thanks.
P.S. here is the code inside the for loop'
            Dim dgvDropDown As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = New DataGridViewComboBoxCell()
            dgvDropDown.DataSource=Form1.table
            dgvDropDown.DisplayMember="adrese_id"
            dgvDropDown.ValueMember="adrese_id"
            DataGridView1.Item(column, row)=dgvDropDown

Comment: Hang on need to alter my datagridview to work with a table instead. I always use classes and bindingsources for DGV handling. Tables are to error prone for my liking.

Comment: Well this worked with a table too. Can't see why it doesn't work for you. Basically you still update the database the same way as you did before. The value is supposed to be updated when you select a new one in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you upload you code inside the for loop, which uses the database. I think my code is not working because I use DataSource to fill the combobox. Are you filling it with Items.add? If yes, then how? thanks)

Comment: How you fill the combobox doesn't matter. Both ways work fine. It's more likely that your problem lies with the data in the DataGridView. I can't supply code that handles database because I don't have enough information from you. Update your post with how you get data, how you store it and how you present it in a DGV. Thanks